# 404 keeps kill me after Wordpress 3.0 and higher

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

what have you done since Wordpress v3.0, all direct PHP files are not working in WP, all are returning `404 page not found`, I have created one plugin, it's loading `/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/direct.php` file and what am I seeing now, it shows me my WP site with title `PAGE NOT FOUND 404`, help me please I can't work with WP any more, all direct PHP files are not accessible and tracked as `404`.
What should I do to turn off that terrible `404` or get my php files loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` file, maybe all `URLs` now are mapped to the `index.php` file of Wordpress.

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*shop/images/(\d+)/?\??(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/shopp/core/image.php?siid=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress

Comment: All rewritrerules  except `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` (tells to do nothing if index.php is directly accessed) should be after the rewriteconds, overwise, the php files match themselves and everything is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided rewrite rules, I would suggest to use this instead:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*shop/images/(\d+)/?\??(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/shopp/core/image.php?siid=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working, all CSS files are not loading and even /wp-admin/ directory shows me 404, wp can't find their admin directory

Comment: And with this EDIT? (duplicated the rewritconds since they probably only apply to the next rule only)

Comment: the result of this new rewrite rules is that all css files not loading, when I click in css file link in HTML source of browser it's show me same HTML code not css file content, and mysite.com/wp-admin/ is start show as 404 page not found

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The rewrite conds clearly state any existing file or folder shouldn't be rewritten. What if you remove the RewriteBase?

Comment: all permalinks are not working if I am removing all rules, direct file accesss is showing: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mysite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Internal server error means (in this case) you've got a syntax error in your .htaccess file (or an infinite loop). What's left in the file now?

Comment: I've uploaded blank .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding the question.  You're saying that you've created a plugin, and it's not calling in the files properly? (I'm assuming by "direct PHP file access" you mean you can't load a particular file that's *within* your plugin directory?)

Sounds like you're not using the correct paths.  You should be using things like WP_PLUGIN_URL constants that are set up for you via WordPress (http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) - i.e it doesn't sound like an .htaccess issue, it sounds like improper coding in the plugin.

Of course, without knowing what code you *are* using, it's difficult to say what the issue could be.

Comment: I am using this code and it loads 404 page of my site <iframe src="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL ?>/myplugin/direct.php"></iframe>

Comment: when you print_r( WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myplugin/direct.php'); does it provide the correct path to the file you want? If so, what's in the direct.php file? Have you checked your error logs to see what's going on? I'm also not 100% sure you can load a plugin file like that. Where is that code? Is it within a template file? are you trying to use it in a file outside of the WP installation? Or are you trying to put it into a post?